# is there a way to manipulate an sql query with a function in Python?

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I am trying to filter id and descriptions queried from a database and apply python functions to them in a python file. In particular, i'm trying to go through the all text in the descriptions to see if any flagged words are contained in the description, and if they do, I would then like to select the id and description from the database. I would like to be able to do this sort of filtration in a way that I don't have to make a new table in the database and in the end I would like it to give me a list of ids and descriptions that contain the flagged words. Can anyone give any examples of how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to make python and your client program do all the work or do you want your database and server to do the work?

Comment: @JonSG I would like python to do the work, I believe, unless it is much easier with the database

Answer (score 0):

You can incorporate the sqlalchemy library, in particular, flask_sqlalchemy. As well as a couple additional libraries you will need to get this working.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, render_template_string, url_for, request, abort, session
#first create database for users
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   description = db.Column(db.String(100))
```

You need to initialize this in your main function, I will leave that to you to do for simplicity.

You then can query this database to find the user id of every user using this bad phrase by:

```
bad_phrase = User.query.filter(description='bad word').all()
```

This should give you the user ids of every user that used this bad word if you added every post to your user database correctly. 'bad_phrase' is also now an object too.

There a quite a few steps to initializing an sqlite or mysql database and then adding, updating, and deleting things from your database. You should be able to find things online to get you started if you have not done so already, but I hope this can help get you started in terms of querying. I also just threw in a bunch of libraries at the beginning that are very helpful for querying and setting up sqlalchemy, not all are necessary for this question.

You can always check the docs too, link: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/